# QTimer Timeout signal emitted multiple times at each timeout event

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I define a QTimer Object in my MainWindow class as follows :

```
QTimer *timer_ld = new QTimer(this) ;
```

and connecting it to slot of MainWindow class :

```
connect(timer_ld , SIGNAL(timeout()) , this , SLOT(timer_ld_timeout())) ;
        timer_ld->start(time_trigge*1000) ;
```

I define timer_ld_timeout() function as follows :

```
void MainWindow::timer_ld_timeout(){
    iter_call_timer += 1 ;
    img_file_path = img_file_path_buff + img_name + QString::number(MainWindow::iter_img) + img_exten ;
    MainWindow::open() ;}
```

the iter_call_timer variable is just for debugging purpose ... 
and in MainWindow::open() function is just a showMessage memeber of a StatusBar which tells me that the value of iter_call_timer .

now let say that the time_trigge variable takes the value of 5 ( be sure that this value never change during the running time) 
the first timeout event occur correctly at about 5 seconds after, but about 100ms later second call occur and after 5 seconds again third call occur and again after 100ms 4th call and so on (i monitor timing using a stopwatch )... 
for example after about 5.2 seconds the iter_call_timer takes the value of 2.

i have no idea why this happens ...

Comment: Provide more complete code.  There is nothing obvious about the sample given which would cause this issue.  I suspect it has something to do with the strange static call to `MainWindow::open()` but really have no way to tell.  Also not sure what "after about 5.2 seconds the iter_call_timer takes the value of 2" means... sounds like perhaps you have multiple instances of MainWindow going on.

Comment: MainWindow::open() just contains statubar->showMessage(QString::number(iter_call_timer) )

Comment: for example let say that at 00:00 the i start the timer at 00:05 i see that the statusbar contain 1 and at 00:05:20 (the right most is in milliseconds) i see that the statusbar contain 2 which should happen at 00:10

Comment: But why are you calling it like this `MainWindow::open()` ?  Anyway, your example is not reproducible, provide something more complete.  (A physical stopwatch? Seriously?)

Comment: please, i'm not a ... i write the value of iter_call_timer to a .txt file and use another program by QFileSystemWatcher to at the event of the change in situation of file ,start QTimer object and i get the interval between the events.

Comment: Are you sure you're not modifying this QTimer  somewhere else in your code? Maybe you are connecting signal or calling something twice ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure of that ... the strange part is here ... some times it works correctly ... i think the problem related to threading ...

Answer (score 0):

Your questions doesn't provide a running example which make it possible to help clearly. Here a example which is working for me and may help you:

I'm not really sure if it is a good approach to monitor file operations with a stop watch. It may necessary to flush the stream or/and configure the buffer size instead. So this example uses `QElapsedTimer` for an internal time measurement.

*elapsed.h*

```
#ifndef ELAPSED_H
#define ELAPSED_H

#include <QElapsedTimer>
extern QElapsedTimer *elapsedTimer;
extern qint64 last, now;

#define printfElapsed \
    now=elapsedTimer->nsecsElapsed();\
    qInfo(__FILE__ ":%d (%lli ns) > dt= %lli ns",__LINE__,now,now-last);\
    last=now;

#endif // ELAPSED_H
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "elapsed.h"
QElapsedTimer *elapsedTimer;
qint64 last=0, now=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    elapsedTimer = new QElapsedTimer();
    elapsedTimer->start();
    printfElapsed;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    const int time_trigge = 5;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void timer_ld_timeout();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include "elapsed.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    printfElapsed;

    QTimer *timer_ld = new QTimer(this) ;

    connect( timer_ld ,
             SIGNAL(timeout()) ,
             this,
             SLOT(timer_ld_timeout()) );

    timer_ld->setInterval(1000);
    printfElapsed;
    timer_ld->start(time_trigge*1000);
}

void
MainWindow::timer_ld_timeout()
{
    printfElapsed;
    static unsigned int iter_call_timer = 0;
    qInfo("%d",++iter_call_timer);
}
```

The application output is like this:

```
Starting /tmp/build-timer-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Release/timer...
timer/main.cpp:12 (103 ns) > dt= 103 ns
timer/mainwindow.cpp:8 (56759122 ns) > dt= 56759019 ns
timer/mainwindow.cpp:18 (56775739 ns) > dt= 16617 ns
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (5065388463 ns) > dt= 5008612724 ns
1
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (10064517746 ns) > dt= 4999129283 ns
2
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (15064648494 ns) > dt= 5000130748 ns
3
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (20061585036 ns) > dt= 4996936542 ns
4
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (25064713109 ns) > dt= 5003128073 ns
5
timer/mainwindow.cpp:25 (30060972992 ns) > dt= 4996259883 ns
6
```

In milliseconds:

```
0.000105
59.170396
0.016693
5166.980454
4999.163593
5000.16246
4999.221772
5001.169682
```

This shows that nearly 60 ms are needed on my computer up to the time the timer will start. Afterwards the timer calls its slot with a small jitter to the expected time.

You say, that you monitor, a switching between 100 ms and 5000 ms. This may have the following reasons:

- Your measurement method.
- You produce overruns.